# Pull list of files in a folder into a Javascript array

Tags: javascript, php, arrays

I'm trying to figure out the best way to pull a list of files in a folder into a Javascript array. What I want to do is say "if an image file with this IDnumber.jpg exists, assign it to this person, but if not use a default image".

I was thinking I could use a PHP script to grab the list of images in a folder and then somehow pull it via JSON into a Javascript array and then compare that list to the ID of the given user, but I'm trying to figure out how to do that and/or if there's a better way.

Comment: Please include some code on what you have tried doing so far and any traceback on what hasn't worked.